# Scenarios to look into while migrating site from IE to Chrome and Edge support

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, migration, cross-browser

We have old web application in traditional Asp.net which allows only IE-11 browser to open. Now we are going open this restriction to Chrome and Edge browsers.

The below are challenges that we identified so far:

1. Ms Tools support wont be there in Chrome and Edge (Like ActiveX Object).
2. Rendering issues - CSS  - we can fix by changing css.
3. Native Xml Support missing - it has alternative with DOMParser() we can achieve this.

I hope many people are already done this kind of migration earlier. Can someone help if you know any other challenges we need to look?

Comment: can you add the url?

Comment: sorry, this is more a question out of curiosity, I expect all browsers to support XML natively, which XML features are you missing on?

Comment: I mean to say the way we used xml document creation and parsing is different than old IE XML Native implementation. it has alternative i already mentioned.

Comment: @Greg, as of now its intranet site only.

Comment: @Siva, If you done the migration, Can you please share like what are the challenges you are faced when doing this activity. Thanks in Advance.